# Piecewise initialisation of std::array

Tags: c++, c++20, stdarray

How can I write an `std::array` concatenation function?

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sza, std::size_t szb>
std::array<T, sza+szb> concat (const std::array<T, sza>& aa, 
                                const std::array<T, szb>& ab)
{
    std::array<T, sza+szb> result;
    std::copy(std::begin(aa), std::end(aa), std::begin(result));
    std::copy(std::begin(ab), std::end(ab), std::begin(result) + sza);
    return result;
}
```

This of course doesn't work when `T` is not default-constructible. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 13):

Explicit template parameter list for lambdas, as shown in [n. m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358645/4944425), were introduced in C++20.

A C++14 solution needs an helper function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... ai, std::size_t... bi>
std::array<T, sizeof...(ai) + sizeof...(bi)>
concat_impl(std::array<T, sizeof...(ai)> const& aa, 
            std::array<T, sizeof...(bi)> const& ab,
            std::index_sequence<ai...>, std::index_sequence<bi...>)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(ai) + sizeof...(bi)>{
      aa[ai]..., ab[bi]...
    };
};

template <typename T, std::size_t sza, std::size_t szb>
std::array<T, sza + szb> concat (std::array<T, sza> const& aa, 
                                 std::array<T, szb> const& ab)
{
    return concat_impl(aa, ab, 
                       std::make_index_sequence<sza>{},
                       std::make_index_sequence<szb>{});
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Convert the parameters to parameter-pack expansions with `std::index_sequence` and a helper lambda.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sza, std::size_t szb>
std::array<T, sza+szb> concat (const std::array<T, sza>& aa, 
                               const std::array<T, szb>& ab)
{
    auto doit = [&]<std::size_t... ai, std::size_t... bi>
        (std::index_sequence<ai...>, std::index_sequence<bi...>)
    {
        return std::array<T, sza+szb>{aa[ai]..., ab[bi]...};
    };
    return doit(std::make_index_sequence<sza>{}, std::make_index_sequence<szb>{});
}
```

Comment: This isn't c++14

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ahh correct gcc failed to warn me about it

Answer (score 6):

With the help of `std::tuple_cat` and `std::apply`, you can

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sza, std::size_t szb>
std::array<T, sza+szb> concat(const std::array<T, sza>& aa, 
                              const std::array<T, szb>& ab)
{
  return std::apply([](auto... elems) { return std::array{elems...}; },
                    std::tuple_cat(aa, ab));
}
```

Comment: Nice. But I believe `std::tuple_cat` isn't required to support any "tuple-like" container until c++23 (despite most implantations actually going ahead and supporting them).

Comment: There was no definition of so-called `tuple-like` until C++23, however, I believe that the standard clearly specified `std::tuple_cat`'s support for `std::array`s before C++23.

Comment: It did not. There was an inforormative note, at best, and the preconditions did not give leeway other than making it UB.